# How can I evaluate a C function from a dynamic library in an R package?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, rparallel

I’m trying to implement parallel computing in an R package that calls C from R with the `.C` function. It seems that the nodes of the cluster can’t access the dynamic library. I have made a parallel socket cluster, like this:

```
cl <- makeCluster(2)
```

I would like to evaluate a C function called `valgrad` from my R package on each of the nodes in my cluster using `clusterEvalQ`, from the R package parallel. However, my code is producing an error. I compile my package, but when I run

```
out <- clusterEvalQ(cl, cresults <- .C(C_valgrad, …))
```

where `…` represents the arguments in the C function `valgrad`. I get this error:

```
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(lapply(cl, recvResult)) : 
  2 nodes produced errors; first error: object 'C_valgrad' not found
```

I suspect there is a problem with `clusterEvalQ`’s ability to access the dynamic library. I attempted to fix this problem by loading the glmm package into the cluster using

```
clusterEvalQ(cl, library(glmm))
```

but that did not fix the problem.

I can evaluate `valgrad` on each of the clusters using the `foreach` function from the foreach R package, like this:

```
out <- foreach(1:no_cores) %dopar% {.C(C_valgrad, …)}
```

`no_cores` is the number of nodes in my cluster. However, this function doesn’t allow any of the results of the evaluation of `valgrad` to be accessed in any subsequent calculation on the cluster.

How can I either

(1) make the results of the evaluation of `valgrad` accessible for later calculations on the cluster or

(2) use `clusterEvalQ` to evaluate `valgrad`?

Comment: "I can evaluate valgrad on each of the clusters using the foreach function ..." - the reason for this is probably because you are on Unix/macOS and use `registerDoParallel(ncores)`, which creates **forked** processes.  Using `cl <- makeCluster(ncores, type = "FORK")` would probably work equally well.  That is, there's should be nothing magic with foreach or its backends here.  The answer by Rui B explains what the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

You have to load the external library. But this is not done with `library` calls, it's done with `dyn.load`.
The following two functions are usefull if you work with more than one operating system, they use the built-in variable `.Platform$dynlib.ext`.
Note also the unload function. You will need it if you develop a C functions library. If you change a C function before testing it the dynamic library has to be unloaded, then (the new version) reloaded.

See **Writing R Extensions**, file R-exts.pdf in the doc folder, section 5 or on [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#System-and-foreign-language-interfaces).

```
dynLoad <- function(dynlib){
    dynlib <- paste(dynlib, .Platform$dynlib.ext, sep = "")
    dyn.load(dynlib)
}

dynUnload <- function(dynlib){
    dynlib <- paste(dynlib, .Platform$dynlib.ext, sep = "")
    dyn.unload(dynlib)
}
```

Comment: Does this still help me if I build the package? **Writing R Extensions** states `.C` provides "an interface to compiled code that has been linked into R, either at build time or via `dyn.load`"